# Critical error when release .Net Maui app in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, maui

I'm releasing .Net Maui app on the stores. In Android is all fine but I have a critical error in App store. I tested my app in debug mode in iOS and it's fine, no problem. But when I released the app on the store, it crashed.

In my app there are a lot of pages with similar functionality so I don't understand the problem. In this page I have a listview as in the code:

```
List<ModelClass> GeneralDBClassResult = new List<ModelClass>();
string companyCode = "";

        public Page(List<ModelClass> fgdbc, string cCode)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadComponents(fgdbc, cCode);
        }

        private async void LoadComponents(List<ModelClass> fgdbc, string cCode)
        {
            try
            {
                companyCode = cCode;
                ThisPage.Title = cCode;

                if (fgdbc != null)
                {
                    GeneralDBClassResult = fgdbc;
                    listView.ItemsSource = fgdbc.Where(c => c.Id >= 0).Where(c => c.Contact_Code == cCode).OrderByDescending(c => c.Samples_Date).GroupBy(c => c.Samples_Date.Year);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                connetionDBClass.PublicErrorInDB(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

This is my listview in XAML:

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listView" IsGroupingEnabled="True" ItemSelected="listView_ItemSelected" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}" GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*" ColumnDefinitions="auto,*,*" Padding="5">

                                    ...

                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

What I get, is an error when I try to add items in the listview in this line

`listView.ItemsSource = fgdbc.Where(c => c.Id >= 0).Where(c => c.Contact_Code == cCode).OrderByDescending(c => c.Samples_Date).GroupBy(c => c.Samples_Date.Year);`

This is the error I got:

```
ObjCRuntime.ObjCException: Objective-C exception thrown.  
Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: 
attempt to insert nil object from 

objects[0]Native stack trace:   0   CoreFoundation 
                     
0x0000000192cb4cc0 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 40128 1   libobjc.A.dylib   
0x000000018bd543d0 objc_exception_throw + 60    2   CoreFoundation  
0x0000000192e5af84 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 1769348
3   CoreFoundation                      
0x0000000192e579c4 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 1755588   4   CoreFoundation    
0x0000000192cb00a8 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 20648 5   CoreFoundation                      
0x0000000192cb139c 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 25500 6   AppName                  
0x0000000106e0bfc8 xamarin_release_block_on_main_thread + 12148 7   AppName                  
0x0000000107110f88 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 2441380   8   AppName                  0x000000010711828c 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 2470824   9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000194d72b98 B3834960-244B-34E4-9EA0-
CA4BB44EF0F3 + 363416   10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000194d714b8 B3834960-244B-
34E4-9EA0-CA4BB44EF0F3 + 357560 11  AppName                  0x0000000106e11640 xamarin_log + 6816  
12  AppName                  0x00000001051544e8 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 34530836 
13  AppName                  0x0000000106cae418 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 63210820 
14  AppName                  0x00000001049a4684 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 26470320 
15  AppName                  0x000000010477fdf0 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 24223516 
16  AppName                  0x0000000105244a8c 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 35515320 
17  AppName                  0x0000000107078fa0 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1818812   18  AppName                  0x0000000106fcf488 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1123748   19  AppName                  0x0000000106fd11d0 

_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1131244   20  AppName                  0x00000001070e7b9c _ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 2272440   21  AppName                  0x00000001070ef1e8 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 2302724   22  Foundation                          0x000000018cfa47ac 6E76DC96-11AF-3B2E-B71E-
215F9CC6E822 + 243628   23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000192d7e128 4230C122-42E8-
383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 864552 24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000192d8a7b4 4230C122-
42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 915380    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000192d0f5e8 
4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 411112   26  CoreFoundation                      
0x0000000192d250d4 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 499924    27  CoreFoundation                      
0x0000000192d2a3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612   28  GraphicsServices                    
0x00000001ce1ef35c GSEventRunModal + 164    29  UIKitCore                           
0x00000001950b76e8 B3834960-244B-34E4-9EA0-CA4BB44EF0F3 + 3790568   30  UIKitCore                           
0x00000001950b734c UIApplicationMain + 340  31  AppName                  0x0000000106e05bb0 
xamarin_UIApplicationMain + 24  32  AppName                  0x000000010514e5a0 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 34506444 
33  AppName                  0x0000000106c94738 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 63105124 

34  AppName                  0x0000000107078fa0 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1818812   35  AppName                  0x0000000106fcdbd8 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1117428   36  AppName                  0x0000000106fd4264 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1143680   37  AppName                  0x000000010707df40 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1839196   38  AppName                  0x0000000106e10e10 xamarin_log + 4720  39  AppName                  
0x00000001070e2d2c 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 2252360   40  dyld                                0x00000001b222adec 8A423F3F-B318-315E-99C7-
05EE532E9C0D + 89580   at UIKit.UITableView.ReloadSectionIndexTitles()   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.ListViewRenderer.ListViewDataSource.OnShortNamesColle
ctionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2.ShortNamesProxy[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Item
sView`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2.ShortNamesProxy[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Item
sView`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnItemsListCollectionChanged(Object sender, 
NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ItemsView`1[[Microso
ft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)   at 

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ItemsView`1[[Microso
ft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, 

Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].GroupedReset()   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ItemsView`1[[Microso
ft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 


PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnCollectionChangedGrouped(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs 
e)   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ItemsView`1[[Microso

ft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnProxyCollectionChanged(Object sender, 
NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ItemsView`1[[Microso
ft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnItemsSourceChanged(Boolean fromGrouping)   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ItemsView`1[[Microso
ft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 

PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].BindableOnPropertyChanged(Object sender, 
PropertyChangedEventArgs e)   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged(String 
propertyName)   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, 

BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, 

Boolean silent)   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, 
Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty property, Object value, Boolean 
fromStyle, Boolean checkAccess)   at 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ItemsView`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Cell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].set_ItemsSource(IEnumerable value)   at 

AppName.Page.LoadComponents(List`1 fgdbc, String cCode)Native stack trace:  0   CoreFoundation                      
0x0000000192cb4cc0 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 40128 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     
0x000000018bd543d0 objc_exception_throw + 60    2   CoreFoundation                      
0x0000000192e5af84 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 1769348   3   CoreFoundation                      
0x0000000192e579c4 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 1755588   4   CoreFoundation                      
0x0000000192cb00a8 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 20648 5   CoreFoundation                      

0x0000000192cb139c 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 25500 6   AppName                  
0x0000000106e0bfc8 xamarin_release_block_on_main_thread + 12148 7   AppName                  
0x0000000107110f88 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 2441380   8   AppName                  0x000000010711828c 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 2470824   9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000194d72b98 B3834960-244B-34E4-9EA0-
CA4BB44EF0F3 + 363416   10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000194d714b8 B3834960-244B-
34E4-9EA0-CA4BB44EF0F3 + 357560 11  AppName                  0x0000000106e11640 xamarin_log + 6816  
12  AppName                  0x00000001051544e8 

_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 34530836 

13  AppName                  0x0000000106cae418 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 63210820 
14  AppName                  0x00000001049a4684 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 26470320 

15  AppName                  0x000000010477fdf0 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 24223516 
16  AppName                  0x0000000105244a8c 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 35515320 
17  AppName                  0x0000000107078fa0 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1818812   18  AppName                  0x0000000106fcf488 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1123748   19  AppName                  0x0000000106fd11d0 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1131244   20  AppName                  0x00000001070e7b9c 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 2272440   21  AppName                  0x00000001070ef1e8 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 2302724   22  Foundation                          0x000000018cfa47ac 6E76DC96-11AF-3B2E-B71E-
215F9CC6E822 + 243628   23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000192d7e128 4230C122-42E8-
383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 864552 24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000192d8a7b4 4230C122-
42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 915380    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000192d0f5e8 
4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 411112   26  CoreFoundation                      
0x0000000192d250d4 4230C122-42E8-383B-BEEC-EE7B61F8BB61 + 499924    27  CoreFoundation                      

0x0000000192d2a3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612   28  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001ce1ef35c GSEventRunModal + 164    29  UIKitCore                           
0x00000001950b76e8 B3834960-244B-34E4-9EA0-CA4BB44EF0F3 + 3790568   30  UIKitCore                           
0x00000001950b734c UIApplicationMain + 340  31  AppName                  0x0000000106e05bb0 
xamarin_UIApplicationMain + 24  32  AppName                  0x000000010514e5a0 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 34506444 
33  AppName                  0x0000000106c94738 
_ZN9GMSx_absl13base_internal10AtomicHookIPFvPKciS3_S3_S3_EE13DummyFunctionES3_iS3_S3_S3_ + 63105124 

34  AppName                  0x0000000107078fa0 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1818812   35  AppName                  0x0000000106fcdbd8 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1117428   36  AppName                  0x0000000106fd4264 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1143680   37  AppName                  0x000000010707df40 
_ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 1839196   38  AppName                  0x0000000106e10e10 xamarin_log + 4720  39  AppName                  
0x00000001070e2d2c _ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode 
+ 2252360   40  dyld                                0x00000001b222adec 8A423F3F-B318-315E-99C7-
05EE532E9C0D + 89580
```

Why I have this problem only in release mode and not in debug mode? How can I solve it?

Comment: There are many people having issues switching from Debug to Release mode. It's usually due to the linker. Did you try  [disabling linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/linking?tabs=vs#linker-behavior)?

Comment: I didn't try because I cannot try my app in release mode with my mac. Could it work in your opinion?

Comment: I didn't have this problem firsthand yet, so I can't guarantee for it. However it can't do worse than making the app crash :)

Comment: @RiccardoMinato Please note it is Apple requirement for AppStore publishing to turn linking on. If linking is off, the application will be rejected from AppStore.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the bin/obj folders and rebuilding in Release mode?

Comment: *"If linking is off, the application will be rejected from AppStore."* - To clarify: turn linking off to see if the problem goes away. Can upload to TestFlight for testing (without publishing to store). If the problem goes away, then you know it is linking related. Then turn linking back on. The next step is to isolate which class or assembly has the problem. Sometimes this requires trial-and-error of specifying what not to link, until the problem goes away

Comment: *"I cannot try my app in release mode with my mac."* Why not? It should be possible to make an iphonesimulator Release Build, and test on Simulator. Granted, some functionality may not work, but can't you avoid such features, for a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake cannot be your fault. I'm guessing this issue is related to the list view in iOS and specifically when you try to group the item using

```
GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}" GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}"
```

Try to change the way, use a collectionView as in this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SK8u3MmXnjE)

It works for me.